# How to recover virus infected files from pendrive in Ubuntu

Tags: files, usb-drive, data-recovery

I need to recover my pictures and files from a pendrive. I used the pendrive in Windows yesterday to download a file. After that when I inserted the pendrive in Ubuntu, it was only showing the trash file, no other files were there. Please help me to recover my files.

Comment: And how did you remove the pendrive from windows? Eject gracefully or did you just take it out of the slot? How is the pendrive formatted?  Seems to me that you are missing files but what virus?!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to explore if the files/folders are hidden. 
   Ctrl + H will display all hidden files in ubuntu.
2. If the files are not present, then its most likely to be deleted.
3. Dont add any file and make sure you dont write anything to the pen drive and try to recover deleted files using some softwares like [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.apart from recycler, there is no hidden files...Installed the testdisk in my ubuntu system...How to use the testdisk to recovery my files from pendrive.

Comment: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step